# MPDF scaling factor gives issue for Font Size when creating PDF

Tags: php, font-size, mpdf

We used mpdf for creating the PDF from HTML. we struck with one issue while creating the PDF.
Font size is scaling in PDF. If I used 42 as it will gives 31.4 size only.

Definately this problem is due to 
//Scale factor
define('_MPDFK', (72/23.5));

Don't to set the scaling factor causing problem.

Any help on this topic will be appriciate.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<h?>` tags, they work fine to change font sizes (h1..h6). To remove **bold** just add:

```
<h3 style="font-weight:normal;"> My text </h3>
```

Answer (score -2):

mPDF uses autosizing on tables. If you are using tables in your HTML you need to set

```
<table style="overflow: wrap">
```

on all your tables. Check the mPDF Manual on Auto-Layout algorithm.

Comment: I added "overflow" and font size still the same.

Comment: my PDF code is huge. I added your code to one of my tables, but the table just shrank.

Comment: Can you show a snippet of the code for one of the tables that shrank? Without that it is hard to establish why its not working.

Comment: "let_peq" and "let_gra" are smaller and bigger fonts, but they don't work :
`echo "<div class='$ven'>" .
     "<br/>\n" .
     "<div class='centrar'>\n" .
     "  <span class='let_gra negrita subray'>Detalle de ventas</span>\n" .
     "</div>\n" .
     "<br/>\n" .
     "<table class='centrar cuadricula' style="overflow: wrap">\n" .
     "  <tr class='fondo_gris'>\n" .
     "    <td class='cuadricula let_peq negrita' $pad>Consec.</td>\n" .`